# Baccarat project in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code for a casino game called Baccarat.
It's written in Python 3 and I would say that I'm a newbie in Python programming and this is my first project.

**Problem 1:**
when I want to quit the game in the first phase of the game it goes to the second phase and asks the next question after typing "q", which is not ok.

```
Bet on Player / Tie / Banker: q
Thanks for playing Baccarat.
**How much money do you want to bet on q:**
```

**Problem 2:**
when I choose one of "Player/Tie/Banker" choices and go to the next question, whatever I write as an input it always shows me the first `elif` condition of the `bet_amount()` function:

```
Bet on Player / Tie / Banker: b
you bet on Banker
How much money do you want to bet on b: **55**
**please type a number between 1 and 10,000**
```

How should I solve these problems?
And what is wrong in my code?

This is my code:

```
import random, string

"""
Casino game, Baccarat:
    there are three choices for users, Player, Tie and Banker. If users choose either player or banker and win
        their money will be doubled. if the rep goes Tie and they had chosen P or B they get a refund.
        otherwise they lose their money. E.g: Kevin bets on player, but Banker wins, he loses his money.
        Kevin bets 100$ on Banker and he wins, he gets 200$.
        Kevin bets on player or banker, bet goes Tie, he gets his 100$ back.
        Kevin bets 100$ on Tie, bet goes Tie, he will get 800$.
    player and banker recieve two cards, if the sum is <= 5, they recieve another card.
        9 is the biggest number in baccarat. if users get a 9, and dealer has 8 or lower number, users win the game.
"""

# list of cards

card_lst = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]

# value of each card

card_value = {"A": 1,
              "2": 2,
              "3": 3,
              "4": 4,
              "5": 5,
              "6": 6,
              "7": 7,
              "8": 8,
              "9": 9,
              "10": 0,
              "J": 0,
              "Q": 0,
              "K": 0}

# the range of money that players can bet

money_range = range(1, 10001)


class color:
    PURPLE = '\033[95m'
    CYAN = '\033[96m'
    DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    END = '\033[0m'


player = "p"
banker = "b"
tie = "t"

# How to use

print(color.BOLD + "Guide:\ntype p for Player, t for Tie and b for Banker and q to quit the game" + color.END)
print()


# choose player / tie / banker to bet

while True:
    chosen_input = input("Bet on Player / Tie / Banker: ")
    if chosen_input in ("p", "P"):
        print("you bet on Player")
        break
    elif chosen_input in ("t", "T"):
        print("you bet on Tie")
        break
    elif chosen_input in ("b", "B"):
        print("you bet on Banker")
        break
    elif chosen_input in ("q", "Q"):
        print("Thanks for playing Baccarat.")
        break
    else:
        print(color.RED + "Please type P for Player, T for Tie or B for Banker" + color.END)


# How much money do you want to bet?

def bet_amount():
    while True:
        betamount_input = input("How much money do you want to bet on %s: " % chosen_input)
        if betamount_input == money_range:
            print("You bet {} on {}".format(betamount_input, chosen_input))
            break
        elif betamount_input != money_range:
            print("please type a number between 1 and 10,000")
            break
        elif betamount_input in ("q", "Q"):
            print("Thanks for playing Baccarat.")
            break


bet_amount()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your program, basically two things are happening:

   - In the `while` loop, you read the choice of who to bet on, and `break` when you have valid input
   - Then you call `bet_amount`

   That means that in order for the "quit" command to do something different than the others, you need to do something other than `break`.  You could use `exit()` instead:

   ```
       elif chosen_input in ("q", "Q"):
           print("Thanks for playing Baccarat.")
           exit()
   ```
2. `input` behaves differently in Python 2 and Python 3.  In Python 2, it parses the input, and if it looks like an integer it returns an integer.  However, in Python 3, it always returns a string (it behaves like `raw_input` in Python 2).  Thus you need to convert `betamount_input` to an integer before comparing to the range.  (And use `betamount_input in money_range`, instead of `==`.)

   You'll probably want to check for the `q` command *before* you try converting the input to an integer, since it will fail with an error if the input does not in fact contain a valid integer.

Comment: problems solved, but how can I avoid value error, when I type "q"? because I convert betamount_input to an integer it shows me a value Error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Comment: I would move the checks around: check for `q` or `Q` _first_, and if it's not, convert to integer.

Comment: Thank you so much,
I exactly don't know how to do it, but I try to find the way, if I wasn't able to do it I will ask you for more help. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem:

At the end of your code you use your function `bet_amount()`, this will run without any conditions so when your while loop ends it will always be executed.

For your second problem:

you should change `if change betamount_input == money_range` to `if betamount_input in money_range` first of all.

Note your `bet_amount()` function isn't actually doing anything though. It prints the amount the player is betting but the amount isn't saved anywhere. You should use a return statement if you want to to something with the value.

Completely honest: you should really learn more before trying this project, you're going to have a lot of problems if you continue like this.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm not doing this project for anybody, I recently passed a python course by Jose Portilla, and I'm just trying to learn python by doing projects. I'll appreciate you if give some tips to me so that I can learn python better.